# Problem when I open the LID of my notebook

Tags: suspend, lid

I've a Acer Aspire E1-410-2832 and I install today Ubuntu 14.10 (no dual boot, just Ubuntu) and everything works fine except when I close the LID, wait a while (to suspend it), and I open it Again: The computer just don't do nothing, even if I press any key or click with the trackpad, nothing happen. I wait for 5 minutes and nothing.

The same happen with Linux Mint, Ubuntu 14.04 and Fedora.

What do you think can be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This work to me: http://thecodecentral.com/2011/01/18/fix-ubuntu-10-10-suspendhibernate-not-working-bug (I use Step 2, not Step 2 (Old)

Answer (score 0):

it is a problem with your video card and graphics drivers. This same exact thing happened to me. After install the correct drivers all the functionality came back. My computer would suspend correctly. the brightness controls returned to working condition. No freeze up. take a couple hours and research your laptops video card and drivers for it.